# Vmware usb driver error

Tags: macos, usb, virtual-machine, vmware-player

When I try connect USB to MAC OS X 10.10 Yosemite guest on VMware player 7 it gave me this error:

The connection for the USB device "name of the connected USB" was unsuccessful. Driver error.

I tried the following:

1. reinstall VMware player
2. delete USB filter
3. make sure that VMware USB service is running
4. install VMware tools on Guest

and doesn't work.

I'm using Windows 8 Pro 64 bit Host OS.

Help me with this error please.

Comment: Given the fact you mentioned a "Yosemite guest on VMware Player 7", I have to assume you're either trying to connect to a Hackintosh VM or you meant "VMware Fusion 7". If it's the former, that's a very niche case and you should upgrade to Player 12. If it's the latter then your question need a bit of editing for clarity.

Comment: @SaxDaddy I upgrade it to Player 12 but the issue still not fixed and I get unknown error.

Comment: if your host OS is Win8, you will not be able to run stock OSX of any version. What you're trying to do is what's called "Hackintosh" may not be straightforward to get working. For more info, check http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: I didn't try to install "Hackintosh", but I upgraded, before seeing your reply, my PC to Windows 10 Pro 64 bit  and I downloaded latest version of VMware then it's working! Thanks @SaxDaddy for trying help me write it as answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact you mentioned a "Yosemite guest on VMware Player 7", I have to assume you're either trying to connect to a Hackintosh VM or you meant "VMware Fusion 7". If it's the former, that's a very niche case and you should upgrade to Player 12. If it's the latter then your question may need a bit of editing for clarity.

If your host OS is Win8, you will not be able to run stock OSX of any version. What you're trying to do is what's called "Hackintosh" may not be straightforward to get working. For more info, check [wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page](http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)